# envoking some flag at openACC to get warning only for the loops that are not admitted to be parallelized

Tags: gpu, openacc

I am putting openACC directives to enhance an existing serial code.
I was wondering if there are any compiler flags that would envoke warning generation for the loops for which the compiler has ignored their parallelization, rather than reading the entire aceleration report
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using PGI, no, sorry.  -Minfo=accel will only give you a full, and yes verbose, report on everything the compiler is doing w.r.t. the OpenACC directives.  I can put in a request for enhancement (RFE) if you think it would help.

My only concern is that the messages about dependencies may be misunderstood if taken out of context.  For example if an outer loop is successfully offloaded to the GPU but the compiler finds a dependency when auto-parallelizing an inner loop.  Without the full output, it might appear that there's more of a problem than there is.

Comment: Yes Sir I am using PGI, thanks for the clarification, my only point was that as the code gets bigger, the report is going to get bigger, so if we could only see the deficient parts somehow it might be helpful, though you guys know the heart of openACC, it was just a friendly suggestion from a user point of view